# After a 301 redirect google finds strange urls

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have the following redirect in .htaccess:

```
Options -MultiViews

    RewriteBase /
    rewritecond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+product\.php\?id=([^\s&]+)&name=([^\s&]+) [NC]
    rewriterule ^ %2/%1? [R=301,L]
    rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    rewritecond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    rewriterule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)?$ /product.php?id=$2&name=$1 [L,QSA]
```

which works great.
Also in place:

```
<base href="/" />
```

However on this page I have links to other pages which work ok when you click on them. They are defined like so:

```
<a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/Roland-HPi50e-Digital-Piano-in-Rosewood/518">
<img src="/files/images/special_roland_hpi50e_160x500px.png" alt="Roland HPi Pianos">
</a>
```

The problem is -  google doing something strange it is finding for example:

`http://www.mysite.co.uk/a product/Roland-HPi50e-Digital-Piano-in-Rosewood/518`

Is there anybody who can help me to sort this problem as I don't know what causes this.
Any help welcome.

Comment: Do you have `a product` text anywhere in your HTML source?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. a product is just a product page with the link on it. e.g www.mysite.co.uk/productx which contains a link as shown.

Comment: Have you tried removing `<base href="/" />`?

Comment: Yes i did but then all the images can't be found. Is the a way around that cause I am willing to try that

Comment: For fixing images use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: I sorted that by adding the / and now the images will work properly. Will this also solve the problem with google finding these strange urls?

Comment: Yes it will solve that problem too.

Comment: That's great I go and sort all that out. Thanks again for all your help is there somewhere where I can tick your answer as correct or give you extra point up?

Comment: ok sure let me post it as answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove this tag:

```
<base href="/" />
```

For **fixing images/css paths** use absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Answer (score 0):

Might possible escape string problem, try this one, hope this will help you

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^out=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://www.mysite.co.uk/Roland-HPi50e-Digital-Piano-in-Rosewood/518 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Thanks for you reply, however I only gave one example of a link on a page and I have several, does it mean I'll have to do this for every link on the page?

Comment: u mean you have to redirect with some kind of conditions ?

Comment: My feeling is that the problem is with the base ref but I just don't know how to solve it because when I remove this all the images etc are not being found. If there is a possibility to redirect with some conditions can they be a general one or do you need to write them for every individual link on that page? Thanks again for looking

Comment: escape string slashes you need to use for all pages, first try on first it works then you may implement for all :)

Comment: I will try it thanks. Hopefully it will solve the problem with google finding the strange urls. It will probably take google a bit to crawl so I'll let you know in good time. Thanks for your help